# Design pattern to handle following scenario

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am searching for a good design pattern for the following scenario,

I need to follow the below steps, after each step i need to update the status in DB. For that i made a separate class UpdateStatusDAO in that updateStatus(String status) will update the details in DB. The steps are,

```
1. Update Status as Processing Started
2. Read File
3. Update Status as Reading Completed
4. Process File 
5. Update Status as File Processing Completed
6. Rename File
7. Update Status as File Rename Completed
8. Update Status as Processing Completed
```

---

```
try{

    UpdateStatusDAO updateStatusDAO = new UpdateStatusDAO();

    updateStatusDAO.updateStatus("Process Started");

    // Read File
    try{

    } catch(Exception e){        
        throw new Exception();
    } finally{
    }

    updateStatusDAO.updateStatus("Reading Completed");

    // Process File
    try{

    } catch(Exception e){
         throw new Exception();
    } finally{
    }

    updateStatusDAO.updateStatus("File Processing Completed");

    // Rename File
    try{

    } catch(Exception e){
         throw new Exception();
    } finally{
    }

    updateStatusDAO.updateStatus("File Rename Completed");

    updateStatusDAO.updateStatus("Processing Completed");


} catch(Exception e){

} finally{

}
```

The thing is that, suppose due to some reason file Processing got failed. Then i need to update status as Reading Completed. Not File Processing Completed. I added as follows,

1. If any Exception happens On ReadFile / Process File i will throw an exception then the further updation will not happens.

Is there any other better way to handle this scenario. ?

Comment: Maybe a `Proxy` class that wrap your file operations and perform status updates: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using a [Finite State Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).  Once each step finishes you will advance to the next step.  If any step fails you will advance to the error state(which you need to create). The error state could always advance to itself until the error is resolved(maybe the resolution of the error could include another set of steps/states, or maybe the resolution would require a hands-on human fix where you would just reset the machine after fixing it).  Each step will have its own task and is independent of the other steps' work.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can use something like a state machine compiler for this (see [SMC](http://smc.sourceforge.net/)). More generally, you can implement your own state machine using the [state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).